# Deleting from asset browser

Tags: modeling

why is it when I drag and drop an asset from the asset browser into the 3d port, and then I delete it, it also deletes in the asset browser.

Answer (score 5):

The *Asset Browser* is displaying the objects that have been marked as assets. If you select *Current File* it displays the objects that have been marked as asset in the current file, if you select *User Library* it displays the objects that have been marked as asset in the file(s) that are in the folder that has been defined in the *Preferences* panel > *File Paths > Asset Libraries > User Libraries*.

If, in your current file, you delete an object that comes from *Current File*, it will be definitely removed from the *Asset Browser*.

If, in your current file, you delete an object that comes from *User Library*, it won't be removed from its original file (unless the current file is part of the user library folder of course), it will still appear under *User Library*. To definitely remove this object from *User Library* you need to open the file it belongs to and delete it.